# Reset Bluetooth Components Without Having to Reboot

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, powershell

Sometimes the bluetooth on my laptop fails to connect properly (either not at all, or sometimes with terrible quality) to a pair of stereo headphones.  Often times I've been able to recover normal functionality by resetting the bluetooth adapter.

However, that doesn't always work.  That leads me to take other measures, like restarting the bluetooth services in Windows.  This never seems to get anywhere and ultimately I end up rebooting my system and everything works again.

I really don't think rebooting should be necessary to resolve this, and so I'd like to know: **Could anyone else suggest some ideas of what other devices / services / processes in Windows might be worth attempting to reset / restart in order to restore proper functionality of the bluetooth device?**

Ultimately I'd like to just write a .ps1 script that I could run whenever this thing acts up, but please don't hesitate to answer just because you may not work with PowerShell.

#### Extra Details:

The specific services I've tried resetting are:

- **Bluetooth Service** (*\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\btwdins.exe*)
- **Bluetooth Support Service** (*\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k bthsvcs*)

My laptop is a Lenovo T61p with a Broadcom Bluetooth Adapter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like the following using an Administrative PowerShell prompt. You can't restart services as a regular user.

```
Get-Service -DisplayName *Bluetooth* | Restart-Service
```

If this works, you may want to throw the that snippet into a ps1 file and set up ps1 files to be "Run as Admin," this link may help you with that: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-run-as-administrator-to-any-file-type-in-windows-vista/

Hope this helps!

(Adding * in front of Bluetooth* solved my issue with an intel chip.)

Comment: That’s not from the command-prompt (`cmd`), that is from a PowerShell prompt (`powershell`).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, that query only hits the services I've already identified and tried resetting, but have had no effect.  Nevertheless +1, for explicitly giving a PS example to do that.

Comment: This works for fixing issues where the 'Listen to Music' operation/service gets caught in a weird state and cannon Connect to BT headphones. There are an infinite amount of forums talking about this issue, and the only solution has been to restart the PC. +inf

Comment: If you want to forcibly restart it, add `-Force` after the last command

Comment: This worked great for me, I have a VM which if I turn off BT, I can't turn it on w/o Reboot, but this worked like a charm!

Comment: `Get-Service -DisplayName *Bluetooth* | Restart-Service -Force` did restart the service but it did not work since the BT hardware isn't recognised by windows (it has been disconnected by "Enable/Disable NetAdapter")

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this issue as well on my T430. My best resolution so far has been to disable then enable the the Bluetooth Radio device in Device Manager (ThinkPad Bluetooth 4.0 on my machine). This usually lets me reconnect to my headset and everything works fine again. Eventually the machine gets to the point where I have to do this every time to connect, but by then it's been running for a few weeks and needs to be rebooted anyhow :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the cmd way of restarting the bluetooth service:

```
net stop "Bluetooth Support Service" && net start "Bluetooth Support Service"
```

If you're using a localized version of Windows, you may need to replace the name of the service with whatever name your service has. Run `net start` to get the name, this will display the list of all running services.

Or you could use a hybrid approach independent of the service name, calling powershell from cmd:

```
powershell -command "Get-Service -Name bthserv | Restart-Service"
```

You need to have elevated/admin rights in both cases. This fixes my Bluetooth stack when it stops connecting to devices.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I've had success with restarting the Radio Management Service (RmSvc). I'm doing a lot of testing with Bluetooth Low Energy devices, and that fixes the occasions where I stop being able to scan for local devices, even after resetting the Bluetooth adapter.

However, the first time I tried this in Powershell, it worked fine, but I was subsequently getting "Cannot top RmSvc service on computer '.'". At that point, resetting the service from the Task Manager worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest bluetooth drivers:
http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php
Normally all components are reset with hardware "radio on/off" button.

Comment: I had a similar problem where my bluetooth headset wouldn't connect after my Windows 7 computer woke up from sleep. Restarting services didn't solve it but *turning the bluetooth radio on/off* (via laptop's wireless radio settings) did the trick. Didn't have to reinstall any drivers.

Comment: This isn't helpful in my case because only Lenovo has compatible drivers for this particular device, afaik. Hard reset, while restarting the device, doesn't resolve the connectivity problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *Bluetooth icon* shown in the system tray, the easiest way to restart the Bluetooth radio is to right-click it to open the context menu, select *Turn Adapter Off*, right-click it again immediately before the icon disappears and select *Turn Adapter On*.

[image: Bluetooth icon context menu]

To turn the *Bluetooth icon* on, open the Start menu and search for *Change Bluetooth settings* (I really don't know where it's located), open it and on the *Options* tab, check the *Show the Bluetooth icon in the notification area* checkbox.

[image: Bluetooth settings dialog]

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**
I never had luck with restarting Bluetooth services and would have to reboot when the device was connected but there was no sound. Today I finally found what service I can restart to fix the issue. I restarted the "Windows Audio" service and immediately I had sound restored to my bluetooth headphones. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

I've frequently had this problem when connecting my Logitech K480 keyboard to my ThinkPad X1. Often when the laptop wakes from a low-power state, either hibernation or sleep, the keyboard won't reconnect, and the only solution is to reboot.

I tried the restarting the Bluetooth services as described above, however that did not work, so I had a look at the Device Manager and noticed that the Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator was disabled (screen shot taken after I re-enabled it):

[image]

Other BT devices were working fine, but I think that's because these were using the LE (Low Energy) Enumerator instead, which was still enabled.

From my earlier research, I read that ThinkPads sometimes have problems re-enabling hardware when coming out of a low-power state.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative (similar) solution:

1. In command prompt list Bluetooth services:

> `sc query | findstr /I bluetooth`

2. Run services.msc, find the services by name listed by the above command, right click and select restart or start if stopped.